# WSO2 get request body using property expression

Tags: api, wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

I want extract request body of a API call returning as a text.

Response from log mediator.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soapenv:Body><text xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/commons/ns/payload">**1**</text></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>
```

I want to extract **1** which is coming in the body. Please see the screenshot.
[image]

I have tried following it didn't work

```
<property expression="$body" name="api_response_status" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following Property Expression worked for me.

```
<property expression="json-eval($.text)" name="api_response_status" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
```